# User submitted images with http:// urls are causing browsers to warn that the page is not secure

Tags: html, https

I'm working for a forum owner who allows users to submit hotlinked images from other domains in their posts.  If they choose to use an http version of the URL, the otherwise clean page becomes insecure in the eyes of a browser, which some percentage of the time triggers a worried email from certain users.

I can't rewrite the urls, since I can't code against the assumption that future off site images will have https available.  For the same reason, I can't use protocol relative src attributes.  I'm unwilling to fetch and cache the images on our server just so that they can be served over https, because of the computational expense involved.

What can I do?  Is there some piece of HTML syntax or some similar which I can use to tell the browser "This image doesn't matter, and doesn't constitute a security threat"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible. The image may not constitute a security threat but MITM attacks could still lead to images other than the intended one being loaded over the network, and who knows what an attacker may want to supplant that image with. My suggestion would be to pass the annoyance on to your users and tell them they can only use https URLs.

Comment: I figured as much.  Thanks.